# Async operation in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am able to select all image src using:

```
var images = $("img");
images.each(function(i, img) {
    var src = $(img).attr('src');
    console.log(src);
});
res.status(200).send({"message" : "OK"});
```

And I can also copy one image from a src using:

```
request(src).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('photo_' + i + '.jpg')).on('close', function(){
    res.status(200).send({"message" : "OK"});
});
```

I now need to copy all images for all the src's but I'm not sure how to combine an async operation in a loop.

Comment: OP, can you please precise what's missing in the answer ?

Answer (score 4):

There are several solutions here:

**1 Use promises and `all`** (if you're already using ES6 or a library like Bluebird)

```
Promise.all(images.map(function(){
    return ... yourAsynchronousOperationPromise
})).then(function(){
   // all done
});
```

Right now this would be conveniently done by first [promisifying](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) the called asynchronous function.

In your case, you could use the Promise ready version of the request package, [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise), but [it's discouraged when using `pipe`](https://github.com/request/request-promise#api-in-detail).

**2 Use a setImmediate based loop:**

```
(function step(){
    var image = images.shift();
    if (!image) return; // finished
    doTheAsynchronousThing(image, function(){
        setImmediate(step);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Could you show me a specific example using promises. I think I will go with promises.

Comment: @tommyd456 Here's an example in my own code: https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs%2Fprefs.js#L143

Comment: I just looked and there's also an already promise ready version of the request package: https://github.com/request/request-promise

Comment: Thanks - what do you think to this approach: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/waiting-for-a-loop-of-async-functions-to-finish-in-node-js/

Comment: This code is buggy as it is written. There's no guarantee transformations will be sent in correct order;

Comment: No, but order is not an issue as long as all the images are copied over

Comment: Then you can use this approach (be careful not using the counter in the callback) but I find it less clean.